# Tabulator setHeaderFilter before inital AJAX call?

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to set a default headerFilter value before the table loads. I tried all the way up to tableBuild callback. Still getting 2 calls to the API, one for the regular non-filtered data then one with the default filter. The column initialValue and defaultValue params do not seem to affect filterHeaders which is why I am going down this rabbit hole.

```
tableBuilt: function () {
     console.log("tableBuilt");
     this.setHeaderFilterValue("status", "Inactive");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `initialHeaderFilter` value during table creation.

```
initialHeaderFilter: [{field: 'fieldName', value: 'filter value'}]
```

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/filter#header

Here is a working example.
https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/r319zaep/40/

Comment: There are more complications when you are trying to use a select with values/text, so when they select something it sends the id value of the dropdown selection. I was having all kinds of issues populating the setting intitalHeaderFilter. I will say your example works though. I do not like how it pre-selects that value if empty regarding 'select' types. Just something not jiving about it all.

Comment: Is there a way to clear the initialHeaderFilter after they choose something?